# Jumping does not work, Unity character controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having problems with my jumping script in Unity. When I press the jump button, nothing happens. My guess is that the ground check is causing this problem. Everything else is set up right: the ground has the ground layer etc.

I have also tried it without the `JumpMethod` and the scripts works perfectly with no Unity errors.

I've tried remaking the ground check.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Floats

    //Speed Settings
    private float movementSpeed;
    public float normalSpeed = 3f;
    public float sprintSpeed = 5f;
    //Stamina
    public float currentStamina;
    public float staminaUsageMultiplier = 2.5f;
    public float stamina = 100f;
    //Gravity
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    //Jump Settings
    public float jumpHight = 3f;
    //Inputs
    private float horInput;
    private float verInput;

    //Bools
    private bool isGrounded;

    //Components
    private CharacterController controller;

    //Vectors
    private Vector3 move;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    //Transforms
    public Transform groundCheck;

    //LayerMaskes
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    private void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        currentStamina = stamina;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MovementMethod();
        GravityMethod();
        JumpMethod();
    }

    void MovementMethod()
    {
        horInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        move = transform.forward * verInput + transform.right * horInput;

        controller.Move(move * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && stamina != 0)
        {
            movementSpeed = sprintSpeed;

            currentStamina -= staminaUsageMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            movementSpeed = normalSpeed;

        }
    }

    void GravityMethod()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.5f, groundLayer);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y <0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void JumpMethod()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHight * -2f * gravity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are checking `isGrounded` from `groundCheck.position` upwards. Logically it 'should be' downwards unless you are walking on the ceiling. Did you check the value of `isGrounded`?

Comment: Anser to the problem is that when calling character controller twice in one script the engine gets a bit of a problem. 

This is not a new error and i heard by people that it has gotten more light recently and that unity is fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

Why do I need to multiply by the gravity constant here?

```
velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHight * -2f * gravity);
```

Also, `sqrt(3 * -2 * -9.8) = 7.67`, and I don't think that `7.67` is enough velocity to get up from the ground.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Check your groundLayer and groundCheckPosition.I guess your gourndLayer is not right or your groundcheck point is too high.You can use Debug.DrawLine to make Phisic.CheckSphere visiable.